# Order of AngularJS attributes interpolations in different browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-browser

I spotted that directive attributes are interpolated in different order in Chrome and FF (also IE). So for example this directive will produce different result in Chrome as in FF:

```
var TestDirective = function () {

    var linkFn = function (scope, element, attrs) {

        attrs.$observe("att1", function () {
            $(element).append(attrs.att1);  
        });

        attrs.$observe("att2", function () {
            $(element).append(attrs.att2);  
        });

        attrs.$observe("att3", function () {
            $(element).append(attrs.att3);    
        });       
    };

    return {
        link: linkFn
    }
};
```

In general this behaviour is not problematic but there are cases where order of interpolation is important. My question is not how to overcome that and what is a reason for different order of interpolation?

There is also working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvMSP/). If it is opened in Chrome and FF (or IE) the result will be different.

Comment: Attributes in HTML just are not ordered?

Comment: Not that they are not ordered.. In Chrome the result is always `123` in FF it is always `321`. So my question is what is a reason that results are different?

Comment: What happens if you use vanilla javascript and not 3rd party libraries?

Comment: It is not problem to overcome that in some way.. More than that I would like to know what is reason for such a behaviour of AngularJS.

Comment: Yes.. I meant interpolation. See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive - search for `$observe`.

Comment: @PrimosK: Interesting. I'm not at all sure they're [using that word correctly](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/interpolate) but I'd have to study the context more. In any case, not **your** problem. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect Angular is looping through the attributes on the elements in the order they appear in the `attributes` map on the `Element` instance. Since that map is *unordered*, the order of iteration is not determined and is up to the implementation of the browser.

Remember that Angular works by comparing the state of your model against the DOM, so the order in which you're setting the attributes in your `MyCtrl` function doesn't come into it. It's the order in which the attribute changes are detected.

This suspicion would tend to be borne out by the fact that this code lists the attributes in the same order as you see them handled by Angular (321 on Firefox, 123 on Chrome):

```
(function() {
    var elm = document.getElementById("theSpan");
    var attrs = elm.attributes;
    var index;
    var item;
    for (index = 0; index < attrs.length; ++index) {
        item = attrs[index];
        if (item.nodeName.substring(0, 3) === "att") {
            display(String(index) + ": " +
                    item.nodeName + "=" +
                    item.nodeValue);
        }
    }

    function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
})();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvMSP/2/)

That's not definitive proof, but it's a strong indication Angular is doing something similar when comparing differences.